# Change "Format type of new input cells" to InputForm

Tags: front-end, customization

In Preferences -> Evaluation there is a menu to change "Format type of new input cells" and the only options available are: StandardForm, TraditionalForm, and Raw InputForm.

[image: menu]

Is it possible to set this to InputForm?

Edit: This is V9.

Comment: By the way, options set with `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, . . .]` last only for the session while those made to `$FrontEnd` should persist.  Thanks for the Accept.  Are you aware that you can both vote for and Accept an answer?  I ask because you didn't not vote for my answer which I assume was an oversight if you liked it well enough to Accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 7 `InputForm` appears in the drop-down list.  You can apply the same setting using:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CommonDefaultFormatTypes->{"Input"->InputForm}]
```

Whether that has the desired effect in recent versions I do not know.